# Problema com requisição Ajax somente para celular

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Tenho um código *Ajax* que pega os dados de um campo simples de mensagem e envia para meu banco de dados sem que a página seja atualizada, só que o problema é que tudo funciona perfeitamente somente pelo computador, quando acesso pelo celular o envio simplesmente não acontece.

***HTML:***

```
<form method="post" action="../controller/SendChatMessage.class.php?act=open_chat&id_unique_talk=<?=$get_id_unique_talk?>&to_id=<?=$get_id_para?>" id="send_message_chat" ajax="true">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <div class="message-area">
            <textarea placeholder="Message" rows="10" name="message" id="txt_message"></textarea>
         </div>
      </div>
      <button style="height:28px;margin-top:-39px !important;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"> <i class="fa fa-send"></i></button>
 </form>
```

***JavaScript:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $("form[ajax=true]").submit(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      var form_data = $(this).serialize();
      var form_url = $(this).attr("action");
      var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();

      $("#loading").show();

      $.ajax({
          url: form_url, 
          type: form_method,      
          data: form_data,     
          cache: false,
          success: function(returnhtml){                          
              $("#result").html(returnhtml); 
              $("#loading").hide();
              document.getElementById('txt_message').value='';
          }           
      });    

  });

});
</script>
```

Será que alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Então, eu tentei também com o data-ajax="true" só que não funcionou mesmo assim no celular, só no pc, quanto a versão do jquery e a versão do meu android é WW_15.0410.1804.61_0, não sei se é isso que vocês estão perguntando

Comment: Esse loading ai nem era pra tá ai, é um campo de mensagem de um chat então ele não precisa aparecer

Comment: ué, ele está porque no computador ele funciona, só no celular que não

Comment: Estranho. Aqui funcionou tanto no iOS quanto no Android.

Comment: Tenta colocando um `error:` e um `alert` pra ver se mostra alguma coisa.